# Adding custom View and ImageView to a single Layout

Tags: android, view

I want to add some images to the View of an app. The app uses a custom view for its normal working but I want some images along with the custom View. I have tried adding a Layout as the contenView in which I added the ImageView and the custom View, but its not comming to the screen.
Can any one give me some idea on this...
thanks in advance.

**Code:**

```
            MyView view;
            LinearLayout ly;
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp;
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams ImageViewlp;


           lp=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

           ImageViewlp=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

          ly=new LinearLayout(this);
          sketchBoard.setBackgroundColor(0);

          ImageView img=new ImageView(this);
          img.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.img);
          ly.addView(img,ImageViewlp);

          view=new MyView(this);
          ly.addView(view);
          this.addContentView(ly, lp);
```

**Edit:**

```
   img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img);
```

I got it solved by changing   `img.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.img);`   with the above one

Comment: Do you see anything? Or just a blank screen?

Comment: It may be easier for folks to help you were you to post any or all of the following: a screen shot of the problem (the app as it currently is); a mockup of what you are trying to achieve; and the *complete* code necessary to replicate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for responding..now i get only the custom view (MyView) on the screen, I want both the images and the custom view (MyView) on the screen at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing this, but this result in drawing a BG color of whatever value R.Drawable.img is

```
 img.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.img);
```

should be

```
 img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img);
```

or better yet actually use the [imageview's drawable resource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) and do

```
 img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;

public class MyImageView extends View {

private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

    private Drawable mImage;
    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

    public MyImageView(Context context,String uri) {
        this(context, null, 0);
     mImage = Drawable.createFromPath(uri);

        mImage.setBounds(0, 0, mImage.getIntrinsicWidth(), mImage.getIntrinsicHeight());
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
            final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

            // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
            if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

                invalidate();
            }

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                    >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
            final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            }
            break;
        }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();
        Log.d("DEBUG", "X: "+mPosX+" Y: "+mPosY);
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        mImage.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

call this through

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class sampleLocalization extends Activity {
    String uri="";
        ImageView img;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        uri="pathname";
        img.setImageResource(new touchview(context,uri));

  }        
}
```