# How to use less drawable resources as possible?

Tags: android, performance, android-image

I'm trying to make a kind of quiz-app relative to the music field where I keep on showing random images and the user takes the answers. For each answer I check in a database whether it is right or not. You can see some examples of what I mean [here](https://www.musictheory.net/exercises/note) and [here](https://www.musictheory.net/exercises/chord). The problem is that I should put in the Android Project a great number of images, which I suppose is not good. So I'm wondering if there is another way for doing that, maybe using sample-images for each element (a single note, a single sharp, the treble clef etc.) and fixing them toghether in some way in order to "build" the final image.. I really don't know. And also, is there a way to verify the answers without internet connection? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a CustomView or views http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html  and have it draw differently, depending on exactly what you're trying to convey. You could use a background as well as images, and draw the lines. 
[Adding custom View and ImageView to a single Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775471/adding-custom-view-and-imageview-to-a-single-layout)   explains how to include images in a CustomView .